# Duda con consulta en symfony 5 con Left Join

Tags: php, sql, symfony, relaciones

Buenas a todos he estado desarrollando una aplicación web en symfony 5.18 la cual me ha servido como estudio, pero ahora me he tenido que enfrentar a una consulta un poco compleja. Les cuento:
Tengo tres entidades que se relacionan entre ellas; Juego, criterio, usuario. Un juego puede tener varios criterios, y un criterio solo puede tener un juego. Cada criterio es emitido por un usuario. Por lo tanto, tengo definidas las siguientes relaciones en los modelos:
Juego:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Criterio::class, mappedBy="juego", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $criterios;
```

Criterio:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Juego::class, inversedBy="criterios")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $juego;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Usuario::class, inversedBy="criterios")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $usuario;
```

Usuario:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Criterio::class, mappedBy="usuario", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $criterios;
```

Mi problema consiste en que tengo que hacer dos consultas que no me funcionan correctamente; necesito saber cuáles son los juegos en los cuales el usuario logueado no ha emitido un criterio, para ello he creado la siguiente consulta en el repositorio de juegos:

```
public function findPendingGamesByUser($user)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("
            SELECT j, c From App:Juego j
            LEFT JOIN j.criterios c
            WHERE c IS NULL
            OR c.usuario != :user
        ")
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ;
}
```

Esto me devuelve todos los juegos, en cambio si quito la línea:
OR c.usuario != :user

Me devuelve los juegos que no tienen ningún criterio, y lo cual sería correcto, y si la modifico asi:

```
OR c.usuario == :user
```

Me devuelve los juegos que no tienen criterios, más los que el usuario logeado ya le ha emitido el criterio.
No logro comprender porque no me funciona la consulta original.
Si alguien pudiera arrojarme un poco de luz estaría agradecido.

***DATOS DE EJEMPLO:***

**Usuarios:(total 2)**

Pedro (Usuario logeado),
Juan,

**Criterios:(total 4)**

Rust Legacy / Pedro,
Rust Legacy / Juan,
Hurtworld / Juan,
Stalker / Pedro

**Juegos:(Total 6)**

Rust Legacy,
Hurtworld,
GTA,
Call of Dutty,
rainbow Six,
Stalker,

**Resultado de la consulta:(total 5)**

Rust Legacy,
Hurtworld,
GTA,
Call of Dutty,
rainbow Six,

Comment: Lo que deberia funcionar es OR, porque en ese caso seria devuelme los juegos que no tienen criterios, o los que tienen criterio y su autor no es el usuario logeado. Lo cual es realmente lo que yo necesito. Sin embargo, no funciona tampoco.

Comment: Ah espera.. ese ultimo comentario cambia todo lo que dijiste arriba... por eso te falla... estas poniendo mal las condiciones... lee lo que acabas de poner... juegos sin criterio O (juegos con criterio y autor distinto al usuario) <--- nota los parentesis...

Comment: Lo que me recomiendas es consultar primero juegos con criterio y autor distinto al usuario?

Comment: Bueno acabo de darme cuenta de algo, lo que me esta ocurriendo es que si unjuego tiene un criterio emitido por el usuario logueado, pero ademas tiene un criterio emitido por otro usuario entonces tambien lo incluye en el resultado

Comment: No es lo que te recomiendo.. es lo que vos estas buscando... tu query no es tan sencillo como parece... Pone un ejemplo de tus datos, un ejemplo de los datos de salida, y de ahi vemos cual es el sql que te sirve... tal vez no es tan trivial como vos lo pensas... y lo que te dije no era en dos querys, era en uno solo... pero si no separas las condiciones con parentesis, es como si fuera una sola....

Comment: Por ejemplo en mis datos de prueba yo tengo 13 juegos, el usuario logeado ha emitido criterios para 3 juegos, asi que deberia devolverme los otros 10 juegos, pero me devuelve 12, porque dos de los 3 juegos en los que el usuario logeado ha emitido su criterio otro usuario tambien lo ha emitido.

Comment: He actualizado el post con unos datos de ejemplo al final. Digame si se entiende lo que esta ocurriendo?

Comment: Amigo por fin pudistes ver los valores que puse de ejemplo, alguna sugerencia de como resolver esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu pregunta hablas de que necesitas 2 consultas, pero solo muestras una, que es la que voy a tratar de ayudarte a resolver.

El problema de tu consulta viene de que si intentas hacer `OR c.usuario == :user` sobre los criterios de un juego, ese criterio debe existir para que `c.usuario` no sea null.

Puesto que los juegos que buscas son los que no tienen criterios con el usuario que le pasas, `c.usuario = :user` nunca te va a dar los valores ya que no existe ese `c.usuario`.

Puedes usar los resultado de una consulta sobre los criterios para incluirlos en una subselect y así sacar los juegos que necesitas.

Obtener ids de los juegos en los que ha participado el usuario.

```
SELECT j.id From App:Criterio c
INNER JOIN c.usuario u
INNER JOIN c.juego j
WHERE u.id = :usuario
```

Obtener los juegos en los que el id de juego no coincida con el de los juegos en los que ha participado el usuario. Incluimos la consulta anterior como una subselect.

```
SELECT j From App:Juego j
WHERE j.id NOT IN (
    SELECT j.id From App:Criterio c
    INNER JOIN c.usuario u
    INNER JOIN c.juego j
    WHERE u.id = :usuario
)
```

Espero que esta ultima consulta sea lo que necesitas.

Comment: También te recomiendo usar el query builder o DQL, en lugar de queries SQL estandar. Esto permite hacer consultas más dinámicas y fáciles de revisar y mantener. https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-with-the-query-builder

Comment: Esta consulta me esta dando un error porque estoy definiendo j dos veces;
SELECT j From App:Juego j
Y:
INNER JOIN c.juego j
El segundo inner join es necesario??
Obviamente probe eliminarlo y no da error pero no me devuelve ningun resultado.

Comment: Amigo me has resulto el problema, finalmente la consulta me quedo de esta manera:



                SELECT j From App:Juego j
                WHERE j.id NOT IN (
                    SELECT jc.id From App:Criterio c
                    INNER JOIN c.usuario u
                    INNER JOIN c.juego jc
                    WHERE u = :user)

Estoy muy agradecido con usted !!!

Comment: De nada :) Si te ha servido por favor dale como respuesta valida o al like.

Comment: La otra consulta de la que hable creo que es un poco mas compleja, Como puedo saber los juegos en los cuales no todos los usuarios con un rol determinado (ROLE_ESPECIALISTA) han emitido su criterio?